# Vue Async Imports with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component, es6-promise

I have a VueJS 2 application in which I'm trying to load specific components depending on different flags in a config JSON file.

My file structure is as follows:

```
root
  config.json
  > src
  >> client
  >>> components
  >>>> dashboard
  >>>>> MenuBarBrand.vue
  > product
  >> product01
  >>> client
  >>>> components
  >>>>> branding
  >>>>>> MenuBrand.vue
  >> product02
  >>> client
  >>>> components
  >>>>> branding
  >>>>>> MenuBrand.vue
```

At the moment I've tried 2 different methods:

Using the webpack import syntax in my MenuBarBrand component:

```
<template>
    <b-navbar-brand href="/dashboard">
        <MenuBrand />
    </b-navbar-brand>
</template>

<script>
import config from '../../../../config.json';
const MenuBrand = import(`../../../../product/${config.product}/components/branding/MenuBrand`); 

export default {
    name: 'MenuBarBrand',
    components: {
         'MenuBrand',
    },
}
</script>
```

which results in the following error:
[image: Error]

or the Vue Async Components local registration syntax:

```
<template>
    <b-navbar-brand href="/dashboard">
        <MenuBrand />
    </b-navbar-brand>
</template>

<script>
import config from '../../../../config.json';

export default {
    name: 'MenuBarBrand',
    components: {
        'MenuBrand': () => import(`../../../../product/${config.product}/components/branding/MenuBrand`)
    },
}
</script>
```

which results in the following error:
[image: Error]

Are there any clear errors that I'm making or are there any specific babel/webpack plugins needed to enable this functionality?

Edit: Adding my loader configuration based on a comment I received:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader',
            options: {
                loaders: {
                    scss: [
                        'vue-style-loader',
                        'css-loader',
                        'sass-loader',
                    ],
                    sass: [
                        'vue-style-loader',
                        'css-loader',
                        'sass-loader?indentedSyntax',
                    ],
                },
            },
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]',
            },
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
        },
        {
            test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
            loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]',
        },
    ],
},
```

Comment: "but neither options seem to be working at the moment." This is not helpful. Please describe the expected behavior.

Comment: The expected behavior is that in either case the import would work correctly and allow me to load my Vue component into the application. Instead, I'm getting errors (which I will attach to the original question).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this through an alternate method.

In the webpack config I pull in my product flag and create a path:

```
const config = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const productPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'product', config.product);
```

Then I set up an alias in the webpack config using this path:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        menuBrandingPath: productPath,
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
},
```

This path is then used in my Vue component to import the proper component:

```
<template>
    <MenuBrand />
</template>

<script>
    import MenuBrand from 'menuBrandingPath/client/components/branding/MenuBrand'; // menuBrandingPath is an alias in the webpack config

    export default {
        name: 'MenuBar',
        components: {
            MenuBrand,
        },
    }
</script>
```

I've intentionally left out error checking with fs and the fallback path I used to make this example easier to understand. Hopefully it helps someone! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `vue-loader` webpack plugin to process the .vue-files in your webpack setup. That enables the `() => import(...)` syntax.

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader'
        },
        (other loaders....)
    ]
},
```

Or, using `require`instead in your original example:

```
<template>
    <b-navbar-brand href="/dashboard">
        <MenuBrand />
    </b-navbar-brand>
</template>

<script>
import config from '../../../../config.json';
const MenuBrand = require(`../../../../product/${config.product}/components/branding/MenuBrand`); 

export default {
    name: 'MenuBarBrand',
    components: {
         'MenuBrand',
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Joachim! I've attached my loader syntax to the original post. As far as I can tell, I am already using vue-loader, but please let me know if there's something I should change!

Comment: Hmm - I meant that you should have the proper `module`-entry in your webpack.conf.js file, that is not what you have shown here. I'll just edit my post to show an example of how I have done it. Also, all of this is mostly to enable async loading, and basically you might be content with synchronous loading, in which case you should just be able to use `require` instead of import in your first example.